# What is this strange harmonic content present in a resonant circuit output waveform?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, ltspice, resonance, harmonics

The following is an LC circuit excited at resonant frequency 15.915Hz (L=10mH, C=10mF.)

I would expect the output to have only the resonant frequency (constantly increasing in amplitude) since the AC source and the natural response are of the same  frequency.

[image]

1. Why is there an underlying frequency of 100mHz?
2. Why is the amplitude not increasing continuously?

Both L and C are defined to have zero resistance (ESR.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circuit has no damping (except the `Rser=1m` default parasitic of the inductor, or the `Rpar=1/Gmin` for the capacitor, if added), so what you see is not the "real" result. Since there is (virtually) no damping then there can be no damped oscillation, so the output should rise to infinity and, possibly, beyond. To correct the output you need to impose a tighter timestep. Here is how the output looks like for an increasing timestep of `1 s` (no effect since it's less than `1/1024` points, by default), then for `1 ms`, and then for `10 us` (`1 us` will not be an improvement over `10 us`):

[image: needs tighter timestep]

If it stops at 1 kV amplitude it's because of the `Rser=1m`. If you set it to zero, it will do what you expect it to do. The reason has to do with how the SPICE engines calculate their timesteps and how very simple, linear circuits, such as this one, can influence it. TLDR: if it's simple and fast, the timestep shall not be constrained. Of course, the simulator tries to do what it can with the given input, so [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigo) applies (which is your case: ideal voltage source, "pure" LC).

Comment: You can also decrease the `Reltol` setting to something like 1e-6 or even 1e-10, the results don't get much better after 1e-6 though.

Comment: @Arsenal True but, to this day, I'm still not sure whether the tighter timestep or the `*tol` settings have the more adverse effect on the simulation time. The point remains that what OP wants is a text-book analysis of an ideal circuit, which the numerical side of SPICE does not, and cannot agree with, given numerical precision.

Answer (score 1):

There may be something hidden with your voltage source if you are getting that result. Possibly LTSpice has created a little bit of series resistance or current limiting because, no-way would the output settle down to an 80 volt peak sinewave without this damping being present. Neither would the perturbations remain at a fairly constant amplitude up to the 50 second point in the plot.

Additionally, your excitation frequency is miscalculated at around the 7th decimal place but even that wouldn't cause the perturbations you see. To get what you see, the excitation frequency would need to be out by about 0.1 Hz so, double check that you didn't use 15.815 Hz instead of 15.915 Hz. In Micro-cap, to get anything like the same response as yours, I would need to drive the tuned circuit with a 0.1 Hz error and have series resistance of about 0.0005 Ω: -

[image]

Circuit simulated: -

[image]

But, if I discard the series damping resistor and slight error in the excitation frequency, the output waveform will do this (as expected): -

[image]

Notice that the waveform has peaked at +/- 10 kV after 200 seconds and, will continue in this fashion theoretically.

Comment: Depending on mode, the damping may also be numerical convergence error.  High Q networks are notoriously hard to simulate. Unfortunately it's also the case LTSpice may insert ESRs when the user may not intend them to be there (i.e. default values).

Comment: @TimWilliams OP has stated that the series resistances are set to zero. While in LTspice setting something to zero might mean using the default value (even if it's non-zero), for inductors, `Rser=0` means zero series resistance.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen they stated L and C, but not V1 (at present, anyway)

Comment: @TimWilliams That's true, but the voltage source has a default (machine precision) zero resistance. In order for it to have any value, it must be explicitely set.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Ah, got it.